# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2014-03-07 10:48:06' to data type int in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the table below I have a table name `UserGroupMapTable` Which has column are listed below and its datatype when I insert it throws error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2014-03-07
>   10:48:06' to data type int

Please help me to do this.

```
Column Datatype
UserID  int
GroupID int
CreatedBy int
CreatedOn DateTime
ModifiedBy int
ModifiedOn Datetime



INSERT INTO UserGroupMapTable(UserID,GroupID,CreatedOn,CreatedBy,ModifiedBy,ModifiedOn) VALUES ((SELECT UserID FROM UserTable WHERE UserFirstName = 'Bhupinder'),(SELECT GroupID FROM GroupsTable WHERE GroupName = 'ReconciliationAdmin'),'2014-03-07 10:48:06' ,1,'2014-03-07 10:48:06',1)
```

Comment: You are correct. A datetime is not an int.

Answer (score 1):

Change the order `ModifiedOn` and `ModifiedBy` in insert list as below

```
INSERT INTO UserGroupMapTable(UserID,GroupID,CreatedOn,CreatedBy,ModifiedOn,ModifiedBy) 
 VALUES ((SELECT UserID FROM UserTable WHERE UserFirstName = 'Bhupinder'),(SELECT GroupID FROM GroupsTable WHERE GroupName = 'ReconciliationAdmin'),'2014-03-07 10:48:06' ,1,'2014-03-07 10:48:06',1)
```